# NHibernate create temp table, insert rows to temp table and JOIN to temp table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, queryover

In NHibernate 3, how would you create temp table, insert 2000 rows to temp table and JOIN a non-temp table to temp table in NHibernate? any examples would be helpful.

Note: I would prefer NOT to use createsql or HQL to get this done.

The only option I could think of would be to create a permanent table and use it as a temp table with key to each set of data. But then I would have to manage deleting the temp data on an ongoing basis.